# pip3 crashing with ImportError

Tags: python, 16.10, pip

I used Python v3.5 to code in with the `tensorflow` package.
Now I tried to upgrade to the newest version and pip3 crashed all the time with following error when I just run `pip3`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 33, in vendored
    __import__(vendored_name, globals(), locals(), level=0)
ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.pkg_resources'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    vendored("pkg_resources")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 36, in vendored
    __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2976, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2962, in _call_aside
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3004, in _initialize_master_working_set
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2535, in activate
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2109, in declare_namespace
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2058, in _handle_ns
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2078, in _rebuild_mod_path
AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

I am using an updated Ubuntu 16.10 and I am not aware of any software changes which could relate to this problem.

FYI: `pip`, the version for Python v2.7, works without problems.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something broke the Pip3 packages. You can reinstall it with:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall python3-pip
```

Comment: I am experiencing the same error on Ubuntu 16.04 but your solution did not work for me.

Comment: @wrkyle: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. You’re welcome to send me a comment with a notification to draw my attention to it. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try upgrading your `pip3` by typing `pip3 install --upgrade pip` in your terminal.

EDIT: changed `pip` to `pip3`

Comment: (1) This will upgrade `pip` for Python 2 and not `pip3` for Python 3. (2) As you can tell by the import paths OP installed Pip with the Debian package manager, which means that Pip can't upgrade itself. -1